# Having trouble getting user password_salt to a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

In my Community model I would like to encrypt personal and confidential notes using the attr_encrypted gem. Each user has a `password_salt` field that I would like to use in the encryption of the content. I've played around with a variety of approaches and can't seem to find a way. This won't work but it will give you an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :notes, :user_id
  attr_encrypted :notes, :key => :encryption_key

  def encryption_key
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    user.password_salt
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :notes, :user_id
  attr_encrypted :notes, :key => :encryption_key

  def encryption_key
    user = User.find(self.user_id)
    user.password_salt
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Community Model you should have

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_encrypted :email, :key => 'a secret key', :attribute => self.user.password_salt

  ....
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. In the attar_encrypted documentation ':attribute' is the database column name for the encrypted field. 'a secret key' should be replaced by whatever 'user.password_salt' is. I could see how the correct syntax for something like :key => self.user.password_salt might work. Still working on this.

Comment: If you review the documentation and provide the correct solution within the next day or two, I'll accept your answer.